# How can I create a pattern of parallel lines that are increasing in distance in Photoshop / Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, patterns

Please see the referenced image to get an idea of what I am referring to.

[image: pic]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Use Blend and Clipping Masks!**

1. Make a text by text tool and write anything!
2. Press <kbd>P</kbd> to select pen tool and draw simple line (you can use line tool too).
3. Remove Fill and Give Stroke to the line eg. 4px.
4. Duplicate your line and drag it down and reduce stroke to very less eg. 1px;
5. Go to `Object → Blend → Blend Options` and change spacing to Specific Steps and enter value like 30 steps or so.
6. Select both layers and press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+B</kbd> or go to `Object → Blend → Make`.
7. Extra: You can expand blending and make group if you want by `Object → Expand` and you can edit your blending however by moving it's child objects by direct selection tool!
   .
8. Move your blending to the bottom of your text Layer. to do so just select your blending group and press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+[</kbd>
9. Now all you have to do is select your text and blend altogether and `Right click → Make Clipping mask` and see magic happening!

[image]

Comment: Why do you expand the blend?

Comment: To make it uneditable. Lol you know it's every vector asset sellers economy who expand everything including text to make it uneditable. 

Comment: Err... when you save it as a PDF without illustrator editing it gets automatically expanded you dont have to do it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share this knowledge and make the accompanying gif! It really helped. Cheers.

Comment: @joojaa lol talking of eps file :D never the mind I just got habitated to expanding stuff lol!!!!